# Unable to connect to server <hostname:port> as user <username> in Perforce when downloading code

Tags: perforce

I have been pulling my hair for the past few weeks. I'm able to login and create a workspace in stream. When code is downloading, after some time it says reconnect or disconnect workspace.

The dialog box says: `Unable to connect to server < hostname:port > as user < username >`

[image: 1]

Comment: Sounds like your Perforce server is down, or isn't at `perforce:1666`, or isn't available on your network.  You'll need to talk to your Perforce admin, or your IT department, or whomever is in charge of making sure that the Perforce server is running and available.

Comment: Another way to put it -- this is no different from trying to go to a website and getting a browser error.  Either the network is dead or the server is dead.  Either way, it's probably not something you can fix solely from the client side, and it's not possible to remotely debug it for you without any information about the server you're trying to connect to or how you normally connect to it (local network?  VPN?  Regular WAN?).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using mac, you can modify

> vim ~/Library/Preferences/com.perforce.p4v/ApplicationSettings.xml

edit

```
<Int varName="ConnectionStartOption">1</Int>
```

to
`<Int varName="ConnectionStartOption">3</Int>`